# Unable to get url variable in .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my script in .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/insights\/case-studies\/casestudies\/([0-9]+)\-national\-insurance\.html$

RewriteRule ^\/insights\/case-studies\/casestudies\/([0-9]+)\-national\-insurance\.html$  /insights/case-studies.html?view=casestudies&p=$1&/national-insurance [L]
```

I am unable to put value in `p=$1`, because I find nothing when I print variable `p`.

`mod_rewrite` is already enabled.

Comment: The RewriteCond is redundant, because you are doing the matching for the URL in the RewriteRule anyway. And have you checked whether the rewrite actually happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leading slash is not needed in .htaccess and you have lot of unnecessary escaping. Try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^insights/case-studies/casestudies/([0-9]+)-national-insurance\.html$ /insights/case-studies.html?view=casestudies&p=$1&/national-insurance [L,QSA,NC]
```